# Line Chart displays open-values only

Tags: highcharts

I'm trying to display a dynamic stockchart with push-data, but unfortunately for some reason the chart only displays the open-values of the data-array, which is problematic for push-values since only the close-values are pushed. Is there a way to avoid that?

Comment: can you provide a jsfiddle with a sample code that would reproduce your problem

Comment: Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/LaKBQ/
You'll notice that the values in the line are the open-values from the data-array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have your chart series set as type 'line'.
A line is only going to show you one value.

Change the type to 'ohlc'

http://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/LaKBQ/2/

```
type: 'ohlc',
```

Comment: I don't want an OHLC-Chart, I want to display a line-chart, but instead of showing the open-values, I want it to show the close-values, because that's what matters on a line-chart.

Comment: In that case, you'll need to parse the data file that is being returned, and create an array of the timestamps and the closing value. the data you are using is formatted specifically for a OHLC type chart.